# window.location.href on ajax success not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to solve this for a while now, but I can't get itworking. When a user clicks a link he's asked to confirm that he wants to take this action. Then a ajax call is made. The script that's called works fine and returns a string where to redirect to.

I've seen several posts here on problems with window.location, buth none of them could solve mine.

My code:

```
function confirm(a,b,c){
        var r=confirm("Are you sure to do this?");
        if(r==true){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/process-action.php",
                async: false,
                data: {a:a,b:b,c:c},
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.href = data;
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If I do `alert(data)` instead of `window.location.href = data` I can see that the correct data is passed. For instance /user/homepage. Yet, the redirection is not taking place.

If tried to replace the relative path with the entire url, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `assign()` instead:

```
window.location.assign(data);
```

`window.location.href` is a property, not a method.

Comment: @reena it should work fine. Check the console for errors

Comment: $.ajax({
  method : "POST",
  url : url,
  data : $("#frmQuestionnaire").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
 }).done(function(msg) {
  
  alert("Response to Question has been saved.");
  
  var data = window.location.href + "&openModal=1&savedRec=" + currentRec;
  window.location.assign(data);
  //alert(location.href);
  
  location.reload();
  
  $('#detQuestionnaire').modal('hide');
  
 });

Answer (score 1):

Location [assign()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp) Method

```
The assign() method is supported in all major browsers.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

`<form action="submit.php" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">`

and your same script will be work.

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: when you are submit form using ajax than you will not able to reload location on success because form will submit to give action. so we have add function onsubmit so form will not submit and you can send data with ajax and reload page successfully without errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use window.location = "someurl";

Comment: This approach does not work in modern Chrome mobile browser on Android.
.assign() approach from Rory McCrossan answer should be used instead.