# Check db and then redirect using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

So it's my first time handling or rather using ajax and it still rattles my mind. I made this ajax function so when everytime I push a button it checks the value of something on db and if it's true then it should redirect. It works fine or rather redirect when I refresh the webpage but that isn't what I was expecting, I was expecting that if the value on the db being checked is "EQUAL TO" or True then it should redirect without me having to refresh the page just so it can do it's stuff. Hoping for some insights, thanks!

My home.php has this:

```
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

My Ajax JS:

```
$.ajax
({
    url: "testjax.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $('#Button').serialize(),
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) 
    {
        if (data.status=='SUCCESS')
        {
            window.location="/anotherdirectory/"; 
        }
        else 
        {}
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log('error:'+e);
    }
});
```

Testjax PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('path/sql.php');
require_once('path/who.php');

$userID = Who::LoggedUserID(); //Found in who.php
$userData = Who::GetUserData($userID);
$userPoints = $userData['points'];

if ($userPoints==0.00)
        {
            $tent='SUCCESS';
        }
        else
        {
            $tent='ERROR';
        }

        $ary=array("status"=>$tent);

        echo json_encode($ary);
?>
```

Comment: Open developers console and see what's happening there.

Comment: ^ I have and didn't output any errors. It just won't redirect, not until I manually refresh the page when the value is 0.

Comment: when you alert (data.status) what do you get?

Comment: `window.location.href="/anotherdirectory/"; `  try once

Comment: @leo_ap I'm not quire sure what you meant by that so I assumed I have to put it on my js file? I've put it below 'datatype' and it still does the same. It only redirects when I refresh the page at the right/equal value.

Comment: @Anant Thanks for the suggestion but it still does the same. I still need to manually refresh before it redirects. :/

Comment: @Tempbiz no no, you should alert inside the success function, just before your `if (data.status=='SUCCESS')`

Comment: @leo_ap I just tried
    {
            (data.status);
            if (data.status=='SUCCESS')
    
and
    {
            (data.status)
            if (data.status=='SUCCESS')
    
but it still didn't output any errors in the web console.

Comment: @Tempbiz  please provide full url there instead of `/anotherdirectory/` . something like `http://.....`  .Also any error in browser developer  console

Comment: @Anant I just did your suggestion but sadly it still didn't redirect without manually refreshing the page. That's one of my current dilemna, it doesn't output any error in the web console or error log so I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

Comment: inside `if (data.status=='SUCCESS')
        {` do `console.log('here');` and check coming or not?

Comment: @Tempbiz you should `alert(data.status)` its just an alert. alert is a javascript build-in function.

Comment: @Anant I currently changed the redirect location to "#" so I can better debug. The 'here' didn't print in console but when I refreshed the page it was printed. I'm wondering why that is the case since from what I've read shouldn't ajax doesn't have the need for refreshing the page?

Comment: @leo_ap I just tried again. I changed the redirect to # to see and when I refresh I can see the pop-up with the words 'SUCCESS' on it. It still seems like I need to manually refresh.

I was wondering if the button has some sort of function where it's 'Class' changes will it collide with what I'm doing hence why it doesn't auto redirect?

Comment: try: `window.location.assign("/anotherdirectory/");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location.href on ajax success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213737/window-location-href-on-ajax-success-not-working)