# Trying to redirect from AJAX post

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, http, redirect

I am trying to call a webmethod from AJAX which is redirecting to a url like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(StoreCode.ToLower() + "/App/home.html?EventClick=True", false);
```

AJAX call:

```
function TokenPost() {
    var token = $('#hdnToken').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/QDC/WebServices.asmx/ChkToken',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "{data:'" + token + "'}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

But my AJAX call is not redirecting to that url.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location.href on ajax success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213737/window-location-href-on-ajax-success-not-working)

Comment: Do you use Asp.net web forms, mvc or webapi ? And does your request hit the backend at all ?

Comment: asp.net webforms and my request hit the backend but doesn't redirect to the url. @OlegI

Comment: @RachitShah did you get any kind of message? 404 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it' s not possible in HttpPost Methods. But you can return link in your HttpPost method from server. And redirect with Javascript Code if ajax returns success.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/QDC/WebServices.asmx/ChkToken',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{data:'" + token + "'}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function (link) {
                window.location.href = link;
            },
            error: function (link) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

In Server Method (I am using this in ASP.NET MVC):

```
string link = "https://...Your Link";

return Json(link, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you are using WebMethod, I think you can return just string, too.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ChkToken(string data)
{
    string link = "...";
    // Do things
    return link;
}
```

This time ajax return can be like this,

```
            success: function (link) {
                window.location.href = link.d;
            },
```

Comment: I think author want to redirect using asp.net methods, not return the url as string and do this through js